# Get Column names from database where columns values is not null - php

Tags: php, mysql

I've got Column names as

id, name, type, jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec

I want to pull get all the column names from Jan to Dec that are not null

Example

```
Jan Feb Mar
10  10  Null
10  10  Null
```

So my output would be just Jan and Feb

Comment: You should design your tables differentially if you want to do things like that. Even tho this would be possible it'll be slow as hell.

Comment: Why would you have columns like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Keo, as it makes it much harder (maybe impossible) to limit the results you are pulling without further PHP processing.  That being said, here is one way to do it with two foreach loops.

```
// change events to your table name and $dbh to database handle
$fields=array("id","name","type");
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from events') as $row) {
    foreach($row as $key=>$value){
        if($value!=""&&$value!=null&&strtolower($value)!="null"&&!in_array($key,$fields)&&strlen($key)>2)
            $fields[]=$key;
    }
}
print_r$fields);
```

Comment: thanks, when I try the code on my table I get (PHP Notice: Undefined variable: dbh in )

Comment: Sorry about that, $dbh is the name of my data base handler, you will have to change it to whatever you database connection is called.  $db is another common one.

Comment: When I ran this correctly it still return Jan, Feb and Mar, but Mar values are all NULL so that should of not returned... again thanks for your help

Comment: I added another check for manually entered nulls, should catch just about any version now.

Comment: is there way to have it start checking after column "type"

(id, name, type, jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec)

so it only checks the months columns

Comment: I added a in_array check and pre-populated the array with your three non-checked fields which should make it more efficient by skipping the fields you listed as well as only checking each month until it finds something.

Comment: hey man thanks a lot for all the help, only prob that I'm seeing is that this won't just return the months that are not null it allow returns all values under that month example "Array ( [0] => Jan [1] => 0 [2] => Feb [3] => 1 ) "  how do I remove [1] and [3] and so on

Comment: Updated again to drop any fields that aren't at least three letters.  ID is manually added so it will remain.  A is_numeric or is_int check would also work, but there are some catches with them that I can't remember off the top of my head.

Comment: I get the following when I use the above code "Array ( [0] => id [1] => name [2] => type [3] => account [4] => metric [5] => goal [6] => Jan [7] => Feb [8] => Mar ) "